# PHP - Update single cell WHERE cell

Tags: php, mysql, cell

I have this database scheme: http://i54.tinypic.com/k9hzc.png

As you can see, I have three columns (id, settings_name, settings_value)

On my website, I have a form. Although, I have a problem updating a SINGLE cell. For example:

```
         $sitename = inputFilter($_POST['sitename']);
         $sitedescription = inputFilter($_POST['sitedescription']);
         $siteurl = inputFilter($_POST['siteurl']);
         $siteemail = inputFilter($_POST['siteemail']);
         $maintenance = inputFilter($_POST['maintenance']);
         $maintenance_text = inputFilter($_POST['maintenance_text']);
         $activitylimit = inputFilter($_POST['activitylimit']);


         //No error found, save the users settings.
         mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET settings_value='$sitename', sitedescription='$sitedescription', siteurl='$siteurl', siteemail='$siteemail', maintenance='$maintenance', maintenance_text='$maintenance_text', activitylimit='$activitylimit'")
         or die(mysql_error());
```

As you can see, the error here is that there is no column named "sitename, siteurl etc", although, there is **cells** that are named this.

My question is, how can I update ex. "sitename" to the value submitted from the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
   $value = inputFilter($value);
   mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET settings_value='$value' where setting_name='$key' limit 1")
         or die(mysql_error());
}
```

this is the fastest way, it will update any key from form.

Answer (score 0):

create an array where each array keys are the field name.

```
$valid_data = array(
    'settings_value' => inputFilter($_POST['sitename']),
    'sitedescription' => inputFilter($_POST['sitedescription']),
    // etc ...
);

foreach ($valid_data as $k => $v)
    $values[] = $k.'=\''.$v.'\'';
if (!empty($values) 
    mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET ".join(',', $values));
```

if you submit "sitename" the query become:

`UPDATE settings SET settings_value='submiten value'`

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE settings SET settings_value = '$sitename' WHERE setting_name = 'sitename';`

Then, of course, you can do it for others:

`UPDATE settings SET settings_value = '$sitedescription' WHERE setting_name = 'sitedescription';`